# How to set dynamic width of body

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic

I'm not good with jquery.
How to set width increases every new object ?

Here is the CSS style for the body I want to set width with:

```
body {
    height: 120%;
    width: 350%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: If you don't set any width, it will automatically expand to the width of what's inside.

Comment: How and when you have new object inside your body?

Comment: @alan0xd7 yes, but i want if i have new object then width expand horizontally, not vertically.

Answer (score 0):

To set width as per content of the child object you can use `auto` as shown below

```
body {
    height: auto;//set height automatically
    width: auto;//set width automatically
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: how if i have new object then width expand horizontally, not vertically

Comment: in that case you need to keep `height:auto;`, see my updated answer

Comment: it just make expand vertically, but i want expand horizontally.

Comment: can you please share your code on jsfiddle link so that i can help you better